# Execute summon item command issues

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need some help with the execute summon item command and here is a example I made from the same type I am using for my server but cannot seem to get it to work.. any chance anyone knows what I did wrong?

```
/execute at @a run summon Minecraft:item ~ ~ ~ {type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"Minecraft:Wither_skeleton_skull"}}
```

It doesn't seem to work. any chance you know how I could fix this command to properly operate?

I am sure this is a issue with the way I have used the commands.

I believe the spot between `Minecraft:item` and the end is the place where the issue happens. I have messed with it and googled for a hour or two now and haven't really got any help from modern commands, only the old ones.

I now have it so that there are no errors, but it summons air. I will try to link or post a image of this:

[image: This should now be a working image]

The death score is for the rest to function but it doesn't seem to work regardless of if it is there. even if I just do @a... but now there are no errors and all my text has Nice colors.

Comment: Could you include the error screenshot in text, as text of code is preferred over images?

Answer (score 0):

1. The correct syntax for summoning an item entity is `/summon minecraft:item <coords> {Item:{<item nbt>}}`, not `summon Minecraft:item  <coords> {type=item,nbt={Item:<item nbt>}}`, which appears to demonstrate some confusion between NBT syntax and selector argument syntax.
2. As of 1.13 the ID for a player head is `player_head`, not `skull`, and player heads do not use damage value.
3. As of 1.13, the names and lores of items are JSON, and therefore need to be in an extra set of quotes.

The correct syntax for the command you are trying to execute is

```
/execute at @a run summon item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:player_head",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"\"Huntert_'s Head\"",Lore:["\"Given Only to the Chosen one\""]},SkullOwner:"_Huntert_"}}}
```

Additionally, there doesn't seem to be a Minceraft user named `_Huntert_`, did you mean `Huntert_`?

Comment: I think using the namespace (`minecraft:`) is still preferred, just not required for summoning an entity (item or otherwise).

Comment: Thank you, that works now. I will refer to this If I have a issue again and forget it, this was really helpful, thanks

Comment: and yes I have the username ____Huntert____, I did mean huntert, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put in coordinates for it to summon to. At the ~~~ your supposed to put in the X position, Y position, and Z position, respectively.